# Firefox shifting image up with longer text

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, firefox

For some reason Firefox is shifting (bumping) an image up within an `li` up when longer text wraps underneath the image. But this does not occur with Chrome and Safari. See images:

**Chrome/Safari:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

Not really sure why it's doing this.
Here's my CSS as well:

```
.crew ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 75px;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-style: italic;
color: #71767d;
font-weight: 300;
position: relative;
width: 117px;
height: 117px;
}

.crew ul li img {
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}

.crew ul li img.top:hover {
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}

.crew ul li p {
margin-top: 120px;
}
```

I've tried stripping out all the margins within the nested elements as well and still shows up goofy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to `.crew ul li`

Comment: @Adrift - OHHH, WHAT THE!?!?! Zany, I thought I had that in there. This just goes to show that I've been staring at this too long. That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Adrift Can you please write your answer as an Answer. ultraloveninja Can you then please mark that answer as the accepted solution. Let's close this question up!

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` **or** `vertical-align: bottom;` to the `.crew ul li`.

EDIT: Already answered by user Adrift. Thanks to him for the answer. (I was a few minutes too late haha)